# Class of variable inside a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, apply

I have a list containing multiple data frames, and they all have a variable called "year". How do I check the class of year inside each dataframe using lapply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can extract the 'year' column by looping over the `list` and check its `class`.  With `sapply`, it returns a `vector` and if we use `lapply`, it would be a `list` output

```
sapply(lst1, function(x) class(x$year))
```

With `R 4.1.0`, the lambda function can be compact

```
sapply(lst1, \(x) class(x$year))
```

Comment: thank you. Follow up question, how do I change all years to the same type (e.g. date)

Comment: @MuhammadKamil it depends on the format for each 'year' column.  If it is different, perhaps want to use `anydate` from `anytime`

Comment: @MuhammadKamil. I think you can't change an integer of four digits to date type. A date needs a day, month and year?!

Comment: @TarJae OP didn't show any example.  So, it is not clear

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that shows:

1. how to check the class(same as akrun) in this example `numeric`
2. change `year` column in all dataframes to `character`

```
# example data:
df_list <- list(df1 = data.frame(year = c(2018, 2020, 2021)),
                df2 = data.frame(year = c(1989, 1988, 1977)))

# check class (same as akruns just using lapply)
lapply(df_list, function(x) class(x$year))

# change the class of year columns in all dataframe to character
list1 <- lapply(df_list, function(x) mutate_at(x, "year", as.character))

# check again
lapply(list1, function(x) class(x$year))
```

Output:

```
> lapply(df_list, function(x) class(x$year))
$df1
[1] "numeric"

$df2
[1] "numeric"

> 
> list1 <- lapply(df_list, function(x) mutate_at(x, "year", as.character))
> 
> lapply(list1, function(x) class(x$year))
$df1
[1] "character"

$df2
[1] "character"
```